# Why does the array appear empty when I start the activity despite having objects?

Tags: android-studio

I am working with a BD rom or DAo everyone calls her in a way. It is a shopping list with 2 activity 1 a recycleView and another to add. When you start the app, the idea is to verify if there is something in the database or in the array of the recycler, if there is, then start it and if not, then go to the activity to add. The problem is that even having products, it tells me that there are none. I leave the code. This is the Main

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 10;
private RecyclerView rv1;
private AdaptadorProducto adaptador;
private List<Producto> datos = new ArrayList<>();
private Context contexto;
private ListaCompraViewModel listaCompraViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    contexto = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listaCompraViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ListaCompraViewModel.class);
    rv1 = findViewById(R.id.rv1);
    adaptador = new AdaptadorProducto(this, datos);
    rv1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    rv1.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rv1.setAdapter(adaptador);
    registerForContextMenu(rv1);
    listaCompraViewModel.getProductos().observe(this, adaptador::setDatos);
    if (datos.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "La lista de la compra esta vacia le enviamos a la opcion de añadir",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, NuevoProductoActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int posicion = -1;
    try {
        posicion = adaptador.getPosicion();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.mi1:
            Snackbar.make(this.rv1, "Se ha elegido borrar el elemento " + posicion, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            Producto p = adaptador.getDatos().get(posicion);
            new borrarProducto(BaseDatosApp.getInstance(contexto)).execute(p);
            adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (datos.isEmpty()) {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialogo1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                dialogo1.setTitle("Infornacion");
                dialogo1.setMessage("La lista de la compra esta vacia añada un producto o salga de la aplicacion");
                dialogo1.setCancelable(false);
                dialogo1.setPositiveButton("Añadir", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
                        añadir();
                    }
                });
                dialogo1.setNegativeButton("Salir", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                dialogo1.show();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.mi2:
            añadir();
    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

public void añadir() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NuevoProductoActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        Producto nProducto = (Producto) data.getExtras().getSerializable("Producto");
        new insertarProducto(BaseDatosApp.getInstance(contexto)).execute(nProducto);
        View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "Se ha insertado un nuevo registro.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
        snackbar.show();
    }
}
class borrarProducto extends AsyncTask { private final BaseDatosApp database;

public borrarProducto(BaseDatosApp database) {
    this.database = database;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(final Producto... params) {
    database.productoDAO().delete(params[0]);
    return null;
}
}

class insertarProducto extends AsyncTask { private final BaseDatosApp database;

public insertarProducto(BaseDatosApp database) {
    this.database = database;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(final Producto... params) {
    database.productoDAO().insertAll(params);
    return null;
}
```

DB

```
  @Database(entities = {Producto.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class BaseDatosApp extends RoomDatabase { private static BaseDatosApp INSTANCIA;

public static BaseDatosApp getInstance(Context context) {
    if (INSTANCIA == null) {
        INSTANCIA = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.getApplicationContext(),
                BaseDatosApp.class,
                "dbCompra")
                .build();
    }
    return INSTANCIA;
}

public static void destroyInstance() {
    INSTANCIA = null;
}
```

other class

```
    ListaCompraViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
private final LiveData<List<Producto>> productos;
public ListaCompraViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    productos = BaseDatosApp
            .getInstance(application)
            .productoDAO().getAll();
}
public LiveData<List<Producto>> getProductos() {
    return productos;
}

    public abstract ProductoDAO productoDAO();
```

Comment: Can you share your insertAll function & Producto entity, maybe check if you are able to execute it without exceptions